# C++: almost identical header files, but one gives a peculiar inheritance-related error

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, virtual-functions

For a C++-project, I need to make a game with Doodlebugs and Ants, which are both Organisms. So, I made a class called `Organism` with the following definition (although I'll probably add way more member functions and member variables, of course).

Organism.h:

```
#ifndef ORGANISM_H
#define ORGANISM_H

#include "World.h"

class Organism
{
    public:
        Organism();
        ~Organism();    

        virtual void Move() = 0;

        friend class World;

        int survivalTime;
};

#endif
```

Organisms live in 'the World', which is a class with (among others) a member variable `Organism*** field`, a two-dimensional dynamic array containing pointers to Organism objects.

World.h:

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H

#include "Organism.h"
#include "Ant.h"
#include "Doodlebug.h"

class World
{
    public:
        World();
        ~World();

        void gameplay();

        Organism*** field;
};

#endif
```

You probably already guessed it: `Ant` and `Doodlebug` are derived from `Organism`.

Ant.h:

```
#ifndef ANT_H
#define ANT_H

#include "Organism.h"

class Ant : public Organism
{
    public:
        Ant();
        ~Ant();
        void Move();
};

#endif
```

Doodlebug.h:

```
#ifndef DOODLEBUG_H
#define DOODLEBUG_H

#include "Organism.h"

class Doodlebug : public Organism
{
    public:
        Doodlebug();
        ~Doodlebug();
        void Move();
};

#endif
```

As you can see, `Ant.h` and `Doodlebug.h` are almost identical, except for the words Doodlebug and Ant. However, I have two errors.

1. In `World.h`, line 16: "'Organism' does not name a type."
2. In `Doodlebug.h`, line 7: "expected class-name before '{' token"

Why is this? The first error can be solved by putting `class Organism;` right before the definition of `class World`, but I don't understand why that changes anything, since the complete definition of `Organism` is in `Organism.h`, which I include.

The second error is the one I'm VERY confused by (and kind of the main reason I'm asking this question), since `Ant.h` is identical to `Doodlebug.h` except for the words `Ant` and `Doodlebug`, but in `Doodlebug.h` I get an error but not in `Ant.h`???

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Organism` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: `Organism.h` now does not include any files.
`World.h` now only includes `Ant.h` and `Doodlebug.h` which include `Organism.h`.
Fortunately, `Organism.h` does NOT need to know anything about `World` since `friend class World` does not require the definition of `World`. So no forward declarations needed.

Answer (score 3):

You have circular dependency between `World.h` and `Organism.h`.

`World.h` has

```
#include "Organism.h"
```

and `Organism.h` has

```
#include "World.h"
```

You can remove the above line from `Organism.h` and replace it with a forward declaration.

```
class World;
```

Use forward declaration in header files if you don't need the definition of a  as a matter of principle. That will not only avoid problems like the one you encountered but it will also reduce compile time dependecies.

Additional references:

[Forward declaration vs include](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/195806/forward-declaration-vs-include)
[When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: I would add that one should use forward declarations whenever it's possible. It allows to avoid most of problems like the given above.

Comment: Forward declarations also improve compilation speed, possibly _a lot_.

Answer (score 2):

You did not post your compile command (and most importantly what is the file you try to compile?), but below is what I think your problem is.

The main problem is that your `Organism.h` includes `World.h`, which in turn tries to include `Organism.h` once again, but does not actually include it due to include guards. Therefore, in `World.h` the compiler still does not know what `Organism` is and thus generates the first error. You can use forward declaration to solve this: just write

```
class Organism;
```

in `World.h` before `class World...`; you can also remove `#include "Organism.h"` from `World.h`.

I suppose that your second problem can be related to this also.

Note that you can use `-E` parameter to `g++` to generate the file as compiler sees it after preprocessing. Very useful to catch these include-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue derives from your include "mess". When `Organism.h` is processed (maybe because a corresponding `Organism.cc` is compiled) the include statement is replaced by the actual contents, i.e. it is replaced by the contents of `World.h`. That effectively yields a translation unit where the declaration of `World` stands before the declaration of `Organism`, hence leading to the error.

Comment: So in `Organism.h`, before `#include "World.h"`, I put a forward declaration, `class Organism`. In `World.h`, I still write `#include "Organism.h"`, because it will not be defined a second time.    I now see why this solves the problem. I didn't realize that `#include` statements basically (or actually) copy the code to the place of the `#include` statement.

Comment: Simply do not include `World.h` in `Organism.h` at all. Just forward-declare `class World;`, that will suffice. And as well don't include `Organism.h` in `World.h`, put a forward declaration for `class Organism;` there instead.

Comment: Yes indeed, `#include` statements _are_ actually copy-and-paste instructions to the preprocessor, literally.

Answer (score 0):

You could also probably remove `#include "Organism.h"` from your `World.h` as you have included that in both your `Ant` and `Doodlebug` classes, and both of those are included in your `World` class.